# Add overlay to choropleth map in plotly.express?

Tags: python, choropleth, plotly

I recently started playing around with the plotly.express library for making choropleth maps. I've been able to create one just fine using a GeoJSON of a state's census tracts and a Pandas dataframe, however, I'd like to add another "layer" on top of the census tracts to show where municipal boundaries are (I have a GeoJSON for this as well). I haven't been able to find a walkthrough/guide where someone does something like this, and I haven't been able to figure out much from the plotly documentation.

Here's my code for the main choropleth plot:

```
fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    geojson= Tracts,
    locations= df['TRACTCE10'],
    color= df['someVariable'],
    color_discrete_map={"None":'LightGray',
                        "Cat1":'LightGreen',
                        "Cat2":'LightPink',
                        "Cat3":'LightSeaGreen'},
    featureidkey= 'properties.tractce10',
    projection='mercator' 
)

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Any advice or links to a possible solution?